# What kind of a number is this $n=\overline{a_k a_{k-1}\dots a_3 a_2 a_1}$

Tags: notation, number-systems

Right now, I am studying number theory and I stumbled upon this number:

$$n=\overline{a_k a_{k-1}\dots a_3 a_2 a_1}$$

I found it in this statement: Number $n$ is divisible by 7  $\iff$ the number $m = \overline{a_9a_8a_7} - \overline{a_6a_5a_4} + \overline{a_3a_2a_1} - \dots$ is also divisible by $7$.

Can someone please explain to me what kind of a number is this?
Thanks!

Comment: That is the notation for "$a_k,\dots,a_1$ are digits of $n$", It seems.

Comment: ...Hopefully in base $10$, otherwise this basis should have been mentionned by a superscript for example.

Comment: For example $\dfrac17=0.142\overline{857142}$ says that $857142$ is the periodic decimal development of the decimal expansion of $\dfrac17$. It could be this?

Comment: @Vepir So this could represent a number with \(k\) digits?

Comment: Notation is not universal; it must be defined. You need to provide the source of this, and you should check to see whether the author has defined this notation previously.

Comment: The $a_i$ are the digits of $n$, written in base $10$. Author is using the fact that $1001$ is divisible by $7$. And that full context would have made it clear to experienced readers here, btw.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you! It's my first time on the platform. Mistakes happen I guess. I'll make sure to provide the full context in my future questions so nobody gets confused.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin"Author is using the fact that 1001 is divisible by 7" why do you say that? we don't know what the actual context is, do we?  I'm seeing a lot of people talking about test of divisibility by $7$ but... why?  That wasn't part of the question was it?

Comment: @fleablood: OP wrote a comment in response to mine quoting from whatever he was writing, in which the statement was that to test divisibility by $7$ you would calculate $\overline{a_3a_2a_1}-\overline{a_6a_5a_4}+\overline{a_9a_8a_7}$, etc. The comment had a MathJax error, perhaps that is why he removed it, but the deletion now makes this unintelligible.

Comment: @Filip: When you removed the comment giving context, *and failed to add the content elsewhere*, you made this even **more** confusing than it was before. Please do not do that. If you are going to remove the information in the comment, at least take the time to add it to the post itself. Otherwise, this is a mess and future readers will have no idea where the comments and answers come from. That’s a disservice to everone, and, frankly, not particularly nice of you.

Comment: Okay, I was just curious. It's a good excercise and the notation of $\overline{a_ka_{k-1}....a_1}$ makes the expressing a *LOT* easier than $\sum_{k=0}^{k-1} a_{k+1}\cdot 10^k$ notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment yes, in this context, this can be used to denote the digits of $n$.

$$n=\overline{a_k\cdots a_2a_1}\iff n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_i\cdot 10^{i-1}$$

Notice that $1000=142\times 7+6$ therefore $\begin{cases}1000\equiv 6\pmod 7\equiv -1\pmod 7\\1000^2\equiv 1\pmod 7\end{cases}$

Let's rewrite our number under the following form:

$\begin{align}n
&=\overline{a_9a_8a_7a_6a_5a_4a_3a_2a_1}\\\\
&=\overline{a_9a_8a_7}\times 1000^2+\overline{a_6a_5a_4}\times 1000+\overline{a_3a_2a_1}\\\\
&\equiv\overline{a_9a_8a_7}\times (1)+\overline{a_6a_5a_4}\times (-1)+\overline{a_3a_2a_1}\pmod 7\end{align}$

Which is the desired expression in your comment, $n$ is divisible by $7\iff\overline{a_9a_8a_7}-\overline{a_6a_5a_4}+\overline{a_3a_2a_1}$ is divisible by $7$.

Here are two examples

- $n=464\,981\,517$ then since $464-981+517=0$ then $n$ is divisible by $7$.
- $n=613\,349\,331$ then since $613-349+331=595=85\times 7$ then $n$ also divisible by $7$.

Comment: We generally cannot tell "by inspection" whether a three-digit number is divisible by 7.  My favorite test at that stage is to take the difference between nine times the last digit and the other two digits, which simultaneously covers 13 (the alternating sum of three-digit blocks also covers both 7 and 13).

Comment: It’s easier to note that $1001=7\times11\times 13$, so $1000\equiv -1\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @zwim Thank you.

Comment: @Filip:  you could still [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4089517/edit) your post to add the full context